# Scientific Discovery Rebus Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, rebus

What scientific discovery is represented by the following image?

NOTE: Some tags have been deliberately omitted since I don't wanna reveal too much

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is

> Governmentium

33-14-16-73-7-117 translates to `As Si S Ta N Ts` - assistants.

??-15-92-22-99 translates to `?? P U Ti Es` - __puties, which I guessed as "deputies".

Given that this was about chemistry, and I know $\text{n}^0$ means neutrons in that context, I looked up "assistant deputy neutron" and came across something called

> Governmentium

However, seeing that it was satire, I skipped past it.

...

It took me like 10 minutes before I realized that that was probably the answer, lol.

There are several sources I could find for this - [this one](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/scientists-discover-heaviest-known-element-governmentium-1.764295) (thanks to @Stiv) is relevant; apparently this joke was originally relevant specifically to Ireland. The relevance of the numbers here is:

> If you look at the Yes/No in each row/column, then there is 1 neutron that is neither assistant nor deputy ("one neutron"), 25 assistant non-deputy, 88 deputy non-assistant, and 198 assistant + deputy neutrinos (see the website for that specific reference).

Comment: I think you really need to add a [relevant link](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/scientists-discover-heaviest-known-element-governmentium-1.764295) and explain the context and what all the numbers in the grid mean too. This specific instance of [the answer] is relevant to Ireland, specifically.

Comment: @Stiv Ah - thanks, I'll add a couple of links and explain more in detail.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino that's much better. And yes, I was also aware that there are multiple versions with different numbers (but the same general gist). The check mark is yours!